# Create encrypted archive on mac, to be read on Windows

Tags: encryption, macos-monterey

On macOS Monterey, I need to create an archive, encrypted with a secure algorithm like aes256. That archive needs to be unarchived on a Windows system, using only programs that come default on Windows installs.

None of the solutions I explored work:

1. `zip  --encrypt archive.zip *`
   Great solution, but encryption algorithm is already broken. I couldn't find a way to use a proper encryption algorithm with the `zip` command line
2. `tar --options “encryption=aes256” -a -cf  archive.zip *` this used to work on previous macOSes but now returns `tar: Undefined option: “encryption"`
3. `tar --options “zip:encryption=aes256” -a -cf  archive.zip *` this used to work on macOS Big Sur but now returns `tar: Unknown module name: “zip"` I Couldn't find a way to install the zip module
4. `tar -czf - * | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -out archive.tar.gz` this works to create a `tar.gz` archive. However I need a `zip` archive. I couldn't find how to make it create a zip archive

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: ZIP support on Windows is on its way out anyway, so why not rely on proper compression software (like 7-Zip) instead?

Comment: Ah interesting. I didn’t know that. I am not famiar with windows. What file extension for archives can windows users can easily open without having to install any app?

Comment: ZIP and CAB. Windows does not support ZIP archives with AES. That’s my point: You _want_ third-party software. If this is truly not an option, please add it to your question.

Comment: I added it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer does not support ZIP archives with AES encryption. It only supports ZipCrypto, which as you say is basically useless. Furthermore, Windows Explorer is truly terrible at dealing with ZIP archives.

The only other archive format Windows Explorer supports is CAB, also called Cabinet. It does not support encryption at all.

What you want is not possible. To facilitate secure file transfer, you need third-party software.

But maybe that third-party software could be the archive itself: You could create a self-extracting archive using 7-Zip (or rather p7zip on macOS).

```
7z a -sfx7z.sfx -pThePassword -mhe My-Archive.exe *
```

You can get the SFX modules from the Windows version of 7-Zip. `7z.sfx` is the Windows GUI SFX module. `-mhe` enables header encryption, hiding even the file names.